# Mac Os 10.13.6 started to reopen all previously opened windows of various applications

Tags: terminal, high-sierra, window-manager, text-editor

I use VSCode as my main text editor, and Sublime Text 3 also.

I don't know what happened, but today my OS decided to show me all ever opened windows of my text editors when I start them from command line.

For example, I want to create a new project in directory `ts` and I expect that only one window of Visual Studio Code opens after I type `code ts` in terminal.

But previous sessions (from other directories) are opened also.

When I opened vscode at first, ALL sessions of vscode I ever created opened (about 30-40 windows) and my old mac air freesed.

I have no idea  why it happens, but how can I turn it back?

P.S. It's not a problem of vscode, same happens with Sublime Text 3.